# how to pass a match object from re.sub as an argument

Tags: python, regex

I'm using re.sub to look for a pattern and replace the matches, with the replacement being conditional based on the match. How do I pass the match as an argument? python-3.7

I've successfully passed 'match' if I use the following:

```
string = re.sub(r"{(.*?)}", replaceVar, string)
```

But this method doesn't allow me to pass additional arguments, which is what I need to do.

```
import re

def matchVar(match, another_argument):
    if match.group(1) == another_argument:
        return f'{{{another_argument}}}'
    else:
        return f'{{{another_argument}[{match.group(1)}]}}'

def replaceVar(string, another_argument):
    string = re.sub(r"{(.*?)}", matchVar(match, another_argument), string)
    return string

string = 'This is a {x} sentence. This is another {y} sentence.'
another_argument = 'x'
string = replaceVar(string, another_argument)
print(string)
```

The string should result in

```
'This is a {x} sentence. This is another {x[y]} sentence.'
```

But instead I'm receiving an error 'NameError: name 'match' is not defined'.

(I understand 'match' isn't defined. I'm not sure how to define 'match'.)

How do I pass 'match' as an argument? Thanks!

Comment: It would help your question to show us clear input and output, and then describe what the regex match/sub is supposed to be doing.

Comment: Hey @TimBiegeleisen! Thanks for the looking at this. I'm not sure how I can show more input and output. (I'm new to coding, so maybe I'm misunderstanding your question). The regex is supposed to match anything starting and ending in curly brackets. It is doing this just fine. It is also supposed to sub matches with {x} if the group matches 'x'. And if the group does not equal 'x', it should sub the matches with {x[group]}, which would be {x[y]} in the example above. If this still isn't clear, please let me know. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use lambda and pass the match

```
string = re.sub(r"{(.*?)}", lambda match :matchVar(match, another_argument), string)
```

Or change the matchVar to `def matchVar(match):`
and pass the function like `re.sub(r"{(.*?)}", matchVar, string)`

Comment: 'string = re.sub(r"{(.*?)}", lambda match :matchVar(match, another_argument), string)' worked perfectly. Thank you!